# method document of object iwebbrowser2 failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error "method document of object iwebbrowser2 failed".. Please look the code below.

```
Sub getIE()
Dim sh As Object, oWin As Object, IE As Object

Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each oWin In sh.Windows
    If TypeName(oWin.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        Set IE = oWin
        Exit For
    End If
Next

MsgBox IE.document.URL

End Sub
```

Comment: check if all of your Internet Explorer (or Chrome) windows are closed

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have opened a site on Internet Explorer. Then run the code. I did not get the error as yours but got object reference error. So, added a check when the object is nothing.

```
Sub getIE()
  Dim sh As Object, oWin As Object, IE As Object

  Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  For Each oWin In sh.Windows
    If TypeName(oWin.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        Set IE = oWin
        Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If Not IE Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox IE.document.URL
  End If

End Sub
```